# Amazon AWS Spring MVC log4j2 logging

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, log4j2

Not sure if it is a right place, but will try here.

I have a Spring MVC app deployed on Amazon Elastic Beantalk, using log4j2.
Locally, the logs work well.
this is the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile
                name="MyFile"
                fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log4j2.log"
                filePattern="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log4j2-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log"
                immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>

            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2000"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug"/>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But on EC2 amazon instance, where the ElasticBeanstalk app is running, no appenders working. even SYSTEM_OUT doesn't logged into `catalina.out`. Absolutely no clue why can that happens :(

Btw before i have experience using ElasticBeanstalk, and usually hadprobs with File appender, but at least log is appended to `catalina.out` .

Any idea what should i check?